# How can i run a select and update query simultaneously from phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a scenerio. I have a field called card_no. Some entries are blank. We don't want to handle that. Some have 16 digit integers and some have the proper data I need. What I need is that I want to select all the records that are 16 digits integer and replace them with xxxxxxxxxxxxLAST4DIGITS (The credit card format). Can i do that via mysql?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to SELECT the rows.

You can apply an UPDATE to a subset of rows matching a condition.

```
UPDATE scenario
SET card_no = CONCAT('xxxxxxxxxxxx', RIGHT(card_no, 4))
WHERE LENGTH(card_no) = 16
```

Comment: my table name is cards and my field name is card_no

Comment: UPDATE `cards` SET 'card_no' = CONCAT('xxxxxxxxxxxx', RIGHT(card_no, 4)) WHERE LENGTH(card_no) = 16

Comment: I have attached a image.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But you have to have this field as `char(4)` as you might want to store a number 0002 as *0002* not just 2. So I would first update the datatype of the field and then update the field entries as desired.

```
-- update datatype
alter table `cards`
modify column `card_no` char(4);

-- update values in card_no
update `cards`
set `card_no` = LPAD(if(length(`card_no`) > 4, substr(`card_no`, -4, 4), `card_no`), 4, '0')
where `card_no` is not null;
```

The 'xxx' append operation you can do at application code side or else it will take extra memory in db.